# Rails - Troubles in getting attributes from relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

Those are my models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :honors, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "honored_id"
  has_many :honor_creators, :through => :honors, :source => :person, :foreign_key => "person_id"

class Group 
  has_many :honorss,:foreign_key => "group_id"

class Honor
  belongs_to :person, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => "person_id"
  belongs_to :honored, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => "honored_id"
  belongs_to :group, :class_name => 'Group', :foreign_key => "group_id"
```

Since the `honors` are shown at the `person#show` page, here is my controller:

```
def show
  ...
  @honors = @person.honors.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => Honor.per_page)
end
```

And my view:

```
<% unless @honors.empty? %>
<% @honors.each do |ho| %>
```

My question is: using the `ho` I get all the attributes from the `honor`, but I want to get the creater of the honor and the group that it belongs. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by accessing

```
ho.person
```

or

```
ho.group
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

```
belongs_to :group, :class_name => 'Group', :foreign_key => "group_id"
```

and

```
belongs_to :group
```

will do the same thing because Rails will assume that class and foreign key when you give it `:group`.

**To get `ho.honor_creator` to work (If I'm assuming correctly), you'll want:**

```
class Person < Model
  has_many :honors, :foreign_key => :creator_id
end

class Honor < Model
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "Person"
end
```

That way, you can set `honor.creator_id = params[:user_id]` and then access the Person with `ho.creator`.

**In other words, I'd redo your models like this:**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :honor, :foreign_key => :recipient_id
  has_many :honors, :foreign_key => :creator_id

class Group 
  has_many :honors

class Honor
  has_many :recipients, :class_name => 'Person' # recipient_id is assumed
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'Person' # creator_id is assumed
  belongs_to :group # group_id is assumed
```

I renamed some columns to hopefully make better sense, and this is done off the top of my head, so I'll look at some reference to ensure my accuracy.

**This will give you access to `honor.creator` and `honor.group`.**

```
<% @honors.each do |honor| %>
  Honor Creator: <%= honor.creator.name %>
  Honor Group: <%= honor.group.name %>
  Honor Recipients: <% honor.recipients.each {|recipient| puts recipient} %>
<% end %>
```

Might have messed up the recipient association, but I'll go look.